# "Dimensions must match" error in tflite conversion with toco

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-lite

I have a custom CNN model (image classifier) trained with TensorFlow estimator, and I'm gonna use it in iOS app after conversion to TensorFlowLite model.

My model has several dropout layers, and batch normalization layers as well. In order to avoid conversion errors and remove those dropout layers in `optimize_for_inference` process,
I have saved `eval_graph.pbtxt` separately beside checkpoint files, so as to use it in `freeze_graph`.

Everything works fine in `freeze_graph`, and `optimize_for_inference` throws no errors either. However, after imported both frozen-model and optimized-model files (both `.pb`) into tensorboard for inspection, I found:

***frozen model before optimization***
[image: freezed model before optimization]

***model after optimization***
[image: model after optimization]

Seems `optimize_for_inference` removed shapes info of input tensor layer, which is not the case if I freeze the model with graph saved in training mode (the default `graph.pbtxt`) and optimize it.

**Environments:**

- Tensorflow 1.8.0 for training;
- Tensorflow 1.13.1 for conversion;

**Codes as follow:**

Excerpt of model_fn, pretty normal:

```py
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    """Model function for CNN."""
    # Input Layer, images aleady reshaped before feed in;
    net = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        features['Pixels'],
        (None, 48, 48, 1),
        name='input_tensor'
    )

    # bn-1
    net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=net,
        training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
    )

    # conv2d-1
    net = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=net,
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=[3, 3],
        padding='same',
        activation=tf.nn.relu
    )

    # conv2ds, dropouts, poolings, bns...

    # CONV2Ds -> DENSEs
    # 48 pixels pooled three times (kernel_sizes=2, strides=2), and final conv2d has 128 neurons;
    net = tf.reshape(net, [-1, 6 * 6 * 128])

    # bn-4
    net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=net,
        training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
    )

    # dense-1
    net = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=net,
        units=256,
        kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
        activation=tf.nn.relu
    )

    # denses, logits, nothing special...

    # In prediction:
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:        
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(...)

    # In evaluation:
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        # hook for saving graph in eval mode, this graph will be used in freezing & optimizing process;
        eval_finish_hook = EvalFinishHook()
        eval_finish_hook.model_dir = params['model_dir']
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            ...,
            evaluation_hooks=[eval_finish_hook]
        )

    # In training:
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(...)
```

and custom eval hook class:

```py
class EvalFinishHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    model_dir = '.'
    _saver = None

    def begin(self):
        self._saver = tf.train.Saver()
        super().begin()

    def end(self, session):
        dst_dir = self.model_dir + 'eval_ckpt'
        self._saver.save(sess=session, save_path=dst_dir + '/eval.ckpt')
        tf.train.write_graph(session.graph.as_graph_def(), dst_dir, 'eval_graph.pbtxt')
        super().end(session)
```

freeze and optimize:

```sh
# freeze graph
echo "freezing checkpoint ${best_step}..."
freeze_graph \
--input_graph=${input_graph} \
--input_checkpoint=${input_checkpoint} \
--input_binary=false \
--output_graph=${frozen_model} \
--output_node_names=${output_names} \

# optimize for inference
echo "optimizing..."
/path/to/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
--input=${frozen_model} \
--output=${optimized_model} \
--frozen_graph=True \
--input_names=${input_names} \
--output_names=${output_names}
```

toco throws error:

```sh
# convert to tflite
echo "converting..."
toco \
--graph_def_file=${optimized_model} \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=${input_names} \
--output_arrays=${output_names} \
--input_shapes=1,48,48,1 \
--output_file=${tflite_model}


# error info
Check failed: dim_x == dim_y (128 vs. 4608)Dimensions must match
```

This error seems reasonable since rank 1&2 of shapes are both unknown.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be after dense:

```
model.add(Dense(.., ..))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(...))
model.add(Dropout(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

optimize_for_inference removes dropout layers from the graph as randomly, it is common to use dropout on the inputs.
Therefore the answer could be YES.

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \ 
--input=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \ 
--output=/tf_files/optimized_graph.pb \ 
--input_names={} \ 
--output_names=result
```

Let's try to custom implementation with RandomUniform, FLOOR, TensorFlowShape, TensorFlowSwitch, TensorFlowMerge, in order to disable error.

Reference: [Dropout Regularization](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-regularization-deep-learning-models-keras/)

Comment: I have tried freeze and optimize graph saved in both eval and train mode, and imported two optimized models into tensorboard for inspection, the only difference is that the `input_tensor` of trained graph has output shape, while the one of eval graph no output shape at all. By the way, i can get tflite from trained graph without any issue; but, from eval graph, get `Dimensions must match` consistently. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

well, it seems that swap `bn-4` and `dense-1` mutes the error. So batch normalization should come AFTER dense in this occasion(say, right behind conv2d->dense reshape).

Answer (score 0):

You should use eval.pbtxt when you are using froze graph instead of graph.pbtxt.

Please let check [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md)

So let`s replace 'None' as zero for the first dimension and for the rest ones replaced size of description vector / matrix.
Another point is to observe matrix multiplication rule which says number of columns of the first operand must match the number of rows of the second operand.

If it helps you, please accept answer.

Comment: Yes, i did. And that's where i got those `Dimensions must match` errors from.

Comment: @keyOfVv I edited my answer, please check it again.